# Create a scrollable container?

Tags: java, awt, scrollpane

How do I create a scrollable container? Now Create a scroll pane object

**ScrollPane myContainer = new ScrollPane();**

so how to add my container into the canvas? i am newbie for java. SO i have no any idea of container.

Comment: Why are you coding with AWT, a library that's been out of date for many years, and not Swing? My suggestion would be to use Swing and check out the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you see comments of your question then You dont need more just add container. Like this

> add(myContainer);

if wamt more details go to : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/awt/designspec/scrollpane.html